# Чтобы в mysql при вводе дублирующей записи выскакивало сообщение "ввели значение которое есть в базе"

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Сделал форму в `swing` на `java`. Соединил с `mysql`, добавил несколько `textfield`, записи добавляются в базу, сделал `unique` в `sql`, чтобы дубли не добавлялись в базу.

Есть кнопка, которая добавляет данные в базу `mysql`. Цель: чтобы при добавлении дублируюшей записи выскакивало

> ввели значение которое есть в базе

Понимаю, что надо сделать через диалоговое окно, но как настроить кнопку так чтобы она узнавала что ввели дубль записи?

[image: Главное окно программы]

[image: Окно с базой]

Comment: Просто в обработке события нажатия на кнопку, где вы добавляете новое значение в БД, проверьте, есть ли в ней та запись, которую вы хотите добавить. Если есть, выкиньте окно с соответствующей ошибкой.

Comment: через try catch сделать?

Comment: Да, можно так. В `try` добавлять запись в БД, если это будет дубликат, то выбросится соответствующее исключение, и в `catch` его можно отловить и показать окно с соответствующей ошибкой.

Comment: Если у вас уже есть ограничение `UNIQUE` на какое-то поле в какой-то таблице, то вы и не сможете добавить новую запись в эту таблицу, так как будет выброшено исключение, поэтому достаточно будет его обработать.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена: в кнопке(добавления в базу) создал try catch и в него добавил JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ("Данные внесены!") если данные уникальные и в случае дубля записи в блоке catch добавил  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Уже есть такая запись!");.

//кнопка

```
c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        try {
            String Kname = t1.getText();
            String Surname = t2.getText();
            String Age = t3.getText();
            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ppl51 (name,surname,age) value ('" + Kname + "','" + Surname + "','" + Age + "')");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Данные внесены!");
        } catch (Exception Err) {
            System.out.println(Err.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Уже есть такая запись!");
        }

    }


});
```